# Electron custom notification design

Tags: html, notifications, electron

How can i setup custom notification design using HTML. I tried electron notification body but there i am not able to use fully html and css. And it is having two buttons which should communicate with web app inside electron app.

```
let myNotification = new Notification('Title', {
    body: 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet'
  })
  myNotification.title = "Title";
  myNotification.body = "<div style='display:flex;'><span>Amit Patel</span><b>Hello world</b></div>";

  myNotification.show();
```

Comment: Add code please

Comment: Please add the code you have tried so far.

Comment: let myNotification = new Notification('Title', {
    body: 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet'
  })
  myNotification.title = "Title";
  myNotification.body = "<div style='display:flex;'><span>Amit Patel</span><b>Hello world</b></div>";
  
  myNotification.onclick = () => {
    console.log('Notification clicked')
  }

  myNotification.show();

Comment: @Infa please help

Comment: If you need help, here I can't do nothing because this program use Node.js. So, up your code or project to github, gitlab... and give me the link. Meanwhile, I leave this . https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/notification#notificationshow https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/notifications